# Passing a parameter using String[] args

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have a strong suspicion I'm being stupid here but I have never seen anyone d this before. In this piece of coursework instead of declaring a variable they are using the string array arguments declared in the main.

```
static public void main(String[] args) {

    RandomAccessFile admin;


    byte init[] = {0};

    if (args.length != 1)
      System.err.println("usage: java {gate_bottom,gate_top}");
```

My Instructions are 
"To  do  this  you  will  need  to  specify  a  parameter.  The  parameter should be either gate_bottom or gate_top"

Where should I specify the parameter so that args contains something?

Comment: I think it might want to say that you will need it to pass from command line when you run the program.

Comment: there is an usage message there, despite incomplete. execute the program like : `java YourClassName gate_bottom` (obviously using the correct class name, that I do not know (incomplete code))

Comment: Are you running the program from an IDE, or the command line?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(args[0].equals("gate_bottom"))

else if(args[0].equals("gate_top"))
```

So when you invoke the program like `myprogram.exe gate_bottom` or `myprogram.exe gate_top` the conditions will be triggered

Comment: dont compare strings with ==, that wont do what u expect it to do. use equals instead.

Comment: I don't use Java so I don't know the syntax offhand